# Which of the following functions are differentiable at $z = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> State whether or not the following functions are differentiable at $z = 0$ :
>
> $$\text{1. }z \mapsto \lvert{z}\rvert^2$$
>   $$\text{2. }z \mapsto \Re{(z)} + \Im{(z)}$$
>   $$\text{3. }z \mapsto \Re{(z)}\Im{(z)}$$
>   *where $z = x + iy$*

My idea was to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to determine where the partial derivative requirements are satisfied.

This is mostly to check whether I am understanding the concepts clearly.

*Let $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y) be the real part and imaginary part of the function in question*

First thing I noticed was that none of them have an imaginary part, and hence $v_x = v_y = 0$ for all the functions.

**First Function:**

- We have $u_x = 2x$ and $u_y = 2y$ hence the function is
  differentiable at (x,y) such that $2x = 0$ and $2y = -0$ which leaves
  us with $(0,0)$

**Second Function**

- We have $u_x = 1$ and $u_y = 1$. Since $1 = 0$ has no solutions, we can conclude the function is not differentiable anywhere.

**Third Function**

- We have $u = xy$ and thus we get that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: What does "differentiable" mean in this context?  (In the $\mathbb C$ sense of complex analysis,  or in the $\mathbb R^2$ sense of real analysis?)

Comment: I would assume in the sense of complex analysis. It is a little odd I guess, that the functions do not have an imaginary part. But the exercise does not specify and it's part of a complex analysis study unit.

Comment: If you are going to use Cauchy-Riemann equations to imply complex-differentiability, then you also need to check differentiability, as a $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ function. You can have functions in which the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, but the function is not complex-differentiable. Your approach can be completed, but for this three examples, I would just check it directly from the definition.

Comment: For example, for $f(z)=|z|^2$ we have $f'(0)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{|z|^2}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\overline{z}}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\overline{z}=0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I see, the CR equations can show a function is *not* differentiable, but aren't sufficient alone to show that it is differentiable.

Comment: The theorem is that CR + Differentiable $\Leftrightarrow$ complex-differentiable. So, if you want $\Rightarrow$, then you need to check both conditions on the left.